# Why does using Framer Motion give me different results

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion, react-18

I have a problem. I am using React version 18 and the AnimatePresence feature in Framer Motion does not work. What is the solution to this problem?

iam trying to but it in lay out put not working ,
what should i do in this problem

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You provided any code for us to help you debug. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)